# How to iterate through xml using javascript while altering the document?

Tags: javascript, xml, iteration, insertafter, xmlnodelist

How can I iterate through a list of xml nodes (tag="items"), and while doing so, inserting a new node in a particular place, in this case when a chileNode value changes (tag="rowNum")?  Here's an example showing my input and my desired output:

Starting xml:

```
<items>
  <item>
     <rowNum>1</rowNum>
     <description>some text</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>1</rowNum>
     <description>some more text</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>2</rowNum>
     <description>some text</description>
  </item>
</items>
```

Desired output:

```
<items>
  <item>
     <rowNum>1</rowNum>
     <description>some text</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>1</rowNum>
     <description>some more text</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>1</rowNum>
     <description>last row 1 item</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>2</rowNum>
     <description>some text</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <rowNum>2</rowNum>
     <description>last row 2 item</description>
  </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a variable for the rownum with an initial value set to e.g. -1
2. loop over the item-elements, but **start at the end**
3. check if the variable-value is different from the content of the rowNum-element. When yes, set the variable-value to the content of the rowNum-element and insert the new node before the nextSibling of the current item-element

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/n5wUC/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/n5wUC/)

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle! Your solution looks great. I'm in the process of porting it to java where I plan to run it in a Groovy script. Thanks again for your quick solution.

Comment: I just wanted to share that I successfully implemented your logic in my Java Groovy script. Thanks again!